# unable to locate or fetch any package when Ubuntu on VMware

Tags: 12.10, apt, updates, vmware

I started out trying to install cloudbiolinux/cloudman/galaxy on 11.04 or 12.04 Enterprise or MASS versions of Ubuntu server on a VMware.

I am unable to move from step 1.  sudo apt-get command either does not locate or does not fetch any thing. and any command i use asks me to apt-get as is not available.

I have essentially scanned all GOOGLE and tried everything suggested (albeit with little understanding)

Please advise.

Comment: What exactly is the output of `sudo apt-get update`? Are you sure you have an internet connection? Try `ping -c 4 4.2.2.2` to check internet connectivity.

Comment: ping works--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 207.038/207.248/207.600/0.598 ms

Comment: sudo apt-get update output is as below please

Comment: [Edit your answer](http://askubuntu.com/posts/310485/edit) and paste the output there. Or paste it in http://paste.ubuntu.com, and give us the URL after clicking paste.

Comment: Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Editing as too long to include all lines same Err  quantal-updates quantal-backports InRelease
Err http://in.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.202 80]
Reading package lists... Done

Comment: sorry. here is the link to the outputhttp://paste.ubuntu.com/5783145/

Comment: Do you use a proxy in your network?

Comment: yes, we are always connected through proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it appears that you are behind a proxy. You might not have correctly configured it for `apt`. So let's do that:

1. Do `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf`
2. Add the following lines:

   ```
   Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxy-address:port/";
   Acquire::ftp::Proxy "ftp://username:password@proxy-address:port/";
   Acquire::https::Proxy "https://username:password@proxy-address:port/";
   ```

   Replace the fields with the correct info.

   > - `username` can be `domain\username`
   > - If your proxy doesn't need authentication, you can remove the `username:password@` part all together.
   > - `proxy-address` can be the IP address or the hostname.
3. Save and close (by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

After adding those lines, try `sudo apt-get update` again.

Comment: Thank you very much. Adding proxy details in the .conf file worked.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to [mark my answer as your accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) when you can, and if you want to, to clearly indicate to others that the issue has been solved.